# Custom HTML,CSS Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Looking for scrollbar that has no inside body, only arrows should available to scroll content. Is it possible? In the snippet, the body has a scrollbar with up and down arrow, I don't want a mid area of scrollbar, just custom arrows that do the same thing(maybe it's called scroll thumb or something else don't know).

```css
body {
height:700px;
overflow:scroll;

}
```

```html
<body>Div with some content</body>
```

Comment: Hi! This is possible using a JS plugin, or writing the plugin yourself. CSS alone does not allow you to customize the scrollbar much.

Comment: it will be okay with js too, kindly suggest plugin, thank you.

Comment: There's quite a few out there if you Google it.

Comment: No rlemon, am not looking for the scroll for a specific div, I want a workable scroll through arrows only.

Comment: read the answers, just because the title isn't 100% a duplicate doesn't mean the answers are not applicable to styling a scroll bar in the browser.

Comment: yeah, so, hide the thumb/button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[here](https://codepen.io/webrexRavi/pen/XxOEZz)
```

icreated pen for it you can see it [here](https://codepen.io/webrexRavi/pen/XxOEZz)

Comment: Can you keep the scrollbar buttons instead of scrollbar track? remove scrollbar track, please!

Comment: edit as per your requirements

Comment: change thumb border to none and background to transperant

Comment: thank you for help.

Comment: answers should contain the code itself, or solution itself, not a link to a third party site.

Comment: you are welcome for help always